# Trying to change a cell value based on user data in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to change the value of cells in multiple sheets based on user input. The user inputs the column that they are trying to change and the value they are changing it to, the row will always stay the same. For some reason, I keep getting a subscript or object-defined error. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
Sub changeValue()
    
    Dim column As Variant
    Dim value As Variant
    
    column = InputBox("Column:")
    value = InputBox("Value:")
    
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(7, column).Value = value
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Right now I am just trying to change the value in one sheet but I would like to extend this to multiple sheets. Thanks!

Comment: If you get a subscript out of range error, then there is no worksheet named "Sheet2" in the active workbook.

Comment: Your column number is being treated as a string.  `Cells(7, "2")` would cause that error.  Change `Dim column As Variant` to `Dim column As Long`.

Comment: You could also delete `Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate`, `With Worksheets("Sheet2")` and `End With` - `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(7, column).Value = value` on its own references the correct worksheet and cell (on the currently active workbook).

Comment: Where did you get teh error, did you debug your code?